# F# - How to efficiently store and load DU / record trees in the database

Tags: sql-server, serialization, f#, deserialization

I model a business domain using F# DU / record trees. It works like a charm and does what it is supposed to do. Typical tree depth is about 2-5. Now I need to persist some parameters (let’s call them `settings`) in the database and then load them at startup. The number of settings is on the order of 100. I also need the ability to edit individual settings in SQL, which means that serializing the whole tree into JSON or something like that looks inconvenient.

However, the business domain is fluid at the current stage. That means that the trees may and will get "re-balanced". Which means that some parameters will get moved here and there and / or renamed / added / deleted. Which further means that modeling F# objects in SQL directly (F# type X -> SQL table X) will double (if not more) the development time.

One of the alternatives is to create a "common grave", which is a table that holds all the settings and then use a long string key made of the parts of the tree (e.g. `object1.object2.object3…`) in order to get a particular setting.

I wonder if there is a better solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to isolate your domain from any persistence scheme or mechanism. This is never done 'by magic', but rather by (mapping) code that you write and maintain.

So keep the domain as a domain (never think of persistence here), and tackle persistence as a separate problem.

If, as you state in the question, it is important to be able to set individual settings manually in the DB, then a completely flat schema is the right thing to do. Then write mappers `Domain -> DB`, and `DB -> Domain`.